# Web services called using SoapClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I develop one `ASP.NET C# Web Services` for upload the files. When I consume that web services and called the `web method` of it that have the arguments with `byte[]` with the size of `100 MB` than it fire the error called `OutOfMemoryException`.

What I face:

1. When I trying to send the `byte[10485760]` with the size of `10 MB` than it successfully worked but when
2. When I trying to send the `byte[104857600]` with the size of '100 MB' than it throw the errors called `OutOfMemoryException`.

I have the one web method in web services that given below.

```
[WebMethod]
    public bool MultiUpload(byte[] abtFile, string sFileName, string sFolderName)
    {
        bool bUploaded = true;

        return bUploaded;
    }
```

And I add the Web service in my ASP web app with the option of `Add Web References`

[image]

I create the object of that web services like this:

```
private FileUpload.FileUploadSoapClient objSoapClient=objSoapClient = new FileUploadSoapClient();
```

and I called the web method of web services like this:

```
byte[] abtBytes=new byte[104857600];//HAVE the bytes of images
sFileName="xyz.jpg";
sFolderName="Uploads/Images";
objSoapClient.MultiUpload(abtBytes, sFileName, sFolderName);
```

while calling the `Web Method` called 'MultiUpload' throws the exception called `OutOfMemoryException`. I don't what I missed.

`Web.config` file code:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="6000000" maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `maxBufferSize` in configuration file.

increase `receiveTimeout` and set `maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967295"`

Comment: Thank you. Can your provide some code, how can I set these values

Comment: Try to modified below things in configuration 

`<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>`

Comment: I already have that code in my `webConfig` file. see my updated question